# sudoku game implementation in cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I want to implement Sudoku Game using cocos2d-x. I already have the sudoku solver and other code for logic. But I don't know how to implement it using cocos2d-x. What class should I use. What should I do in GameScene?

Could anyone give me some suggestion and some learning material. I find most learning material is about cocos2d-x 2.0.

Thank you Very much!

Comment: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/programmersguide/

Comment: there is github project on cocos2d-x 2.x . But, reading this code should help you. https://github.com/huster-zhangpeng/cocos2dx-sudoku